# App with admin area to add articles

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, parse-platform

Someone asked me to create a simple app for a used clothing store. Users that download the app see the available items in the store and get a push notification whenever new items are added (without ever having to log in).

The owner of the store needs to have access to an admin area to be able to upload descriptions and pictures of new items so that they appear in the app. Is there an elegant way to let the owner access an admin area inside the app that is invisible to regular users? I'm afraid that a login button or something like that will confuse the regular users. I guess the standard way would be to create a seperate app, or a web-based admin area for the owner, but it would be nice if I could somehow contain it all in a single app in an elegant way that I haven't considered yet.

Comment: Why not just use the Data Browser parse.com website?  Its UI is pretty elegant as is and it would save you the time of having to develop that.

Comment: @DanielBank At first I thought that the risk of the owner accidently messing something up was too great. Now I think that maybe it's an option after all, but it looks like it's not possible to enter new a newline when editing a string property in the data browser, which would be a bit of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that a simple app or a web admin interface would be more typical. But there are still a few things you can do.

Personally, if I was doing something like this, and I wanted a "back door" into the app that you could only access if you knew about it (ie, a regular user would never find it), I would create a custom gesture recognizer and couple that with an admin password.

For example:

Create a custom gesture recogizer for when a user starts at the bottom left of the screen, scrolls to the right corner, then up to the top right corner, then to the left corner, then down. This would then bring up a dialog that says something like "enter admin passord:" and you enter a password that is set somewhere and it displays the admin area. Or you could even have an entire login interface hidden right here to display to the admin.

So for a typical user to actually do this gesture, without a reason or indication to do it, is pretty close to impossible, but still possible. Thus the need for the admin password dialog. With this implementation, only users who have been givin the admin information have the ability to get into it.

However, this may make the app unnecessarily big, as only 1 user (or the number of admins) would use this functionality. But thats all up to your design.

Comment: Android has something similar where you tap the same point seven times to enable debug mode: https://plus.google.com/+PaulIrish/posts/g2m4BBCrzJK